# Variable associated types / data types in Haskell

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, monad-transformers, associated-types

I'm currently trying to overload `MonadTrans`former extraction functions. My current attempt was to place the inner-monad `m` as an instance of an associated type `Result`:

```
class ( Monad Result
      , MonadTrans m
      , MonadReader prefix m
      , ) => FooReader prefix m where
  type Result
  runFooReader :: forall b. m b -> prefix -> Result b

instance Monad m => FooReader prefix (ReaderT prefix m)
  type Result = m -- This is there the error is thrown
  runFooReader = runReaderT
```

The only reason why `Foo` is shaped funny is due to the `MonadTrans` and `MonadReader` restrictions. Basically, this is forcing all associated type instances to be monomorphic types (correct?).

I then thought to redesign it, to make `Result` simply a polymorphic vairable:

```
...
class FooReader prefix m where
  runFooReader :: forall b result. m b -> prefix -> result b
```

... but then in the instances, the types `result` and `w` (if it's `ReaderT prefix w` as `m`, for instance) **will not unify**. Is there any way to make this `result` varialbe / idea polymorphic, yet decidable?

Comment: Try `class FooReader prefix m | prefix -> m`, which is what `mtl` and the like do (and it is probably what you want). If I understand correctly, you want to write a function "run" which takes an arbitrary "monad transformer stack" and "unwraps" it, essentially behaving like `runStateT`, `runReaderT`, `runReaderT . runStateT`, etc, depending on the type. I remember writing some code which did this - it worked but the type errors were horrendous, overall much much effort than its worth - so just stick defining functions for specific types which you encounter often.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cleaning up the syntax errors and adding a kind annotation to `Result`, we get this:

```
class ( Monad Result
      , MonadTrans m
      , MonadReader prefix m
      ) => FooReader prefix m where
  type Result :: * -> *
  runFooReader :: forall b. m b -> prefix -> Result b

instance Monad m => FooReader prefix (ReaderT prefix m) where
  type Result = m -- Again, error triggered here
  runFooReader = runReaderT
```

And a more interesting error:

```
The RHS of an associated type declaration mentions type variable `m'
  All such variables must be bound on the LHS
```

This is expanded in [the GHC docs](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.3/docs/html/users_guide/type-families.html#assoc-decl):

> The visibility of class parameters in the right-hand side of
>   associated family instances depends solely on the parameters of the
>   family. As an example, consider the simple class declaration
>
> ```
> class C a b where 
>   data T a
> ```
>
> Only one of the two class parameters is a
>   parameter to the data family. Hence, the following instance
>   declaration is invalid:
>
> ```
> instance C [c] d where
>   data T [c] = MkT (c, d)    -- WRONG!!  'd' is not in scope
> ```
>
> Here, the right-hand side of the data instance mentions
>   the type variable d that does not occur in its left-hand side. We
>   cannot admit such data instances as they would compromise type safety.

To explore the "it would compromise type safety" point, imagine this GHCi session:

```
> :kind! Result
Result :: * -> *
= {- ... well, what? m? -}
```

You probably mean `type Result prefix (ReaderT prefix m) = m`.

There are still errors remaining. Notably, the kind of `m` is inconsistent; `MonadTrans` needs a parameter of kind `(* -> *) -> * -> *` while `MonadReader`'s second parameter needs `* -> *`. I don't see why you need `MonadTrans`.

I don't understand what you mean by "forcing all associated type instances to be monomorphic types"; the `Result` type you've written isn't really a type function, because it doesn't have any parameters; there aren't any type variables on its LHS.

Here's something that compiles:

```
class ( Monad (Result m)
      , MonadReader prefix m
      ) => FooReader prefix (m :: * -> *) where
  type Result m :: * -> *
  runFooReader :: forall b. m b -> prefix -> Result m b

instance Monad m => FooReader prefix (ReaderT prefix m) where
  type Result (ReaderT prefix m) = m
  runFooReader = runReaderT
```

```
> :kind! Result (ReaderT Int IO)
Result (ReaderT Int IO) :: * -> *
= IO
```

Comment: My apologies, the `MonadTrans` superclass was a mistake, however this was exactly what I needed. Thank you sincerely :)